# How to select all the Textareas which have their id in a particular pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Am new to jQuery and I know about `class`, `id` and `name` selectors in jQuery.

In my HTML I have 6 textarea elements whose Ids are unique and there is a particular pattern with which the ID starts(ex: id= "TA1", id= "TA2".. and so on..  ).

My question is, in jQuery is there a way select all these textarea elements whose ID start with a particular pattern and end with a particular pattern  ?

**Edit:**
Want the combination of both start and end patterns

Comment: Thanks you guys! I have one more issue.. how do I combine this with to select only tags that start with 'TA' and ends with 'some other patern'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ca use the selector like

```
$('textarea[id^="TA"]');
```

Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

**Edit:**
for combining you can use like this, let see the ending patters is **22,**32,**42  so "2" is ur ending pattern.

```
 $('textarea[id^="TA"]').filter('[id$="2"]');
```

Answer (score 4):

try doing like:

```
$("textarea[id^='TA']");
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [attribute starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("[id^='TA']"). ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('textarea[id^="TA"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pattern for IDs is simple (begins with `a` ends with `b`), than you can use

```
$('textarea[id^="a"]').filter('[id$="b"]');
```

for more complex patterns you can use James Padolsey's [filter](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) that allows to use regular expressions like

```
$("textarea:regex(id, a.*some-text-in-the-middle.*b)");
```

Documentation on standard jQuery selectors you can find [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Selectors&redirect=no)